# How to set $LD_LIBRARY_PATH in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables

I need to do this:

> On linux, we have to find a few
>   dynamic libraries which are not on a
>   standard location. We have to set
>   $LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /path/to/sdk/lib

How can I do that in Ubuntu 10.10?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To define this variable, simply use (on the shell prompt):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/sdk/lib"
```

To make it permanent, you can edit the ldconfig files. First, create a new file such as:

```
sudo vi /etc/ld.so.conf.d/your_lib.conf
```

Second, add the path in the created file

```
/path/to/sdk/lib
```

Finally, run ldconfig to update the cache.

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: Are the quotes necessary for LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: @SAFX yes, if the path has spaces or special characters and if they are not escaped.

Comment: This may not work for some versions of Ubuntu. See: [LD_LIBRARY_PATH not loading from .profile nor /etc/environment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/366728)

Answer (score 7):

In bash, assign it before the executable to be run.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/sdk/lib ./somedevtool
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the

> `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/sdk/lib"`

to export the path to the compilers.  
Default path is in `usr/bin`  
Copy and paste the path into the `your_lib.conf` file in the location `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` then save and exit.

> `sudo ldconfig`

Run this to confirm the changes in the files which added the paths